# inline models editor MVC3. Again

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

amigos..
I have one more trouble. 
Stupid may be, but I can't see, what's wrong.

```
    public ActionResult Images(Guid? id)
    {
        ViewBag.Gallery = _core.GetGalleryByID(_client, (Guid)id);

        List<ImageModel> models = new List<ImageModel>();

        foreach (var img in _core.GetImagesByGalleryID(_client, (Guid)id))
        {
            ImageModel model = new ImageModel(_client);
            model.Thumbneil = img.Thumbneil;
            model.Description = img.Description;
            model.AlternateText = img.AlternateText;
            model.GalleryID = img.GalleryID;
            model.ID = img.ID;
            models.Add(model);
        }

        ViewBag.Images = models;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveImageInfo(ImageModel imageModel)
    {
        Image img = _core.GetImageByID(_client, imageModel.ID);
        img.AlternateText = imageModel.AlternateText;
        img.Description = imageModel.Description;

        _core.SaveImageInfo(_client, img);
        return View();
    }
```

This is part of controller.
This is part of view:

```
@model WebUI.Models.ImageModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Images";
    Layout = "~/Views/Admin/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Gallery.Name</h2>

<table id="grid-table" >

    @foreach (var image in ViewBag.Images)
    {
    <tr>
        ....
        <td >
            @using(Html.BeginForm("SaveImageInfo", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description) <br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AlternateText) <br />

                <div id="item-post" >
                    <input title="Подтвердить" type="submit" value="Подтвердить" />
                </div>
            }
        </td>

    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

And model:

```
    public class ImageModel
{
    public Byte[] Thumbneil { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid GalleryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String AlternateText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

In ActionResult SaveImageInfo(ImageModel imageModel) I should have 2 Guids: ID and GalleryID. BUT.
I have this:
[image: watch at run time]
And this is my question: WHY? I can't see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to add a HiddenFor for GalleryId in the view:

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GalleryId)

Comment: is the hidden field GalleryID rendered in the HTML?

Comment: also of course the case should be @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GalleryID)

Comment: No, It's not rendered. <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="98b65624-6aa7-4a9c-97bd-a3871e6a6e19" /><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The GalleryID field is required." id="GalleryID" name="GalleryID" type="hidden" value="" />

Comment: ok so the value of the hidden field GalleryId is empty so the problem must be with the source data....i.e. model.GalleryID = img.GalleryID;
isnt working. Also as an aside, I'd suggest using Automapper to map your source objects to your view models...much easier than typing out the mapping manually.

Comment: I think, problem in @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID) and around, because heare: @foreach (var image in ViewBag.Images) I see all IDs...